# Data of mdt-cell using ng-repeat is not updated

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using `iamisti mdDataTable` in my application. I am showing data using following code.

```
<mdt-row ng-repeat="nutrition in nutritionList" table-row-id="nutrition.id">
  <mdt-cell editable-field="smallEditDialog" key="name">{{nutrition.name}}</mdt-cell>
  <mdt-cell key="calories">{{nutrition.calories}}</mdt-cell>
  <mdt-cell key="fat">{{nutrition.fat}}</mdt-cell>
  <mdt-cell key="carbs">{{nutrition.carbs}}</mdt-cell>
  <mdt-cell key="protein">{{nutrition.protein}}</mdt-cell>
  <mdt-cell key="sodium">{{nutrition.sodium}}</mdt-cell>
  <mdt-cell key="calcium">{{nutrition.calcium}}</mdt-cell>
  <mdt-cell key="iron">{{nutrition.iron}}</mdt-cell>
</mdt-row>
```

It works fine here. When I update the data of `$scope.nutritionList` dynamically, that is not being reflected in view of `mdDatatable`.

Thanks.

Comment: It's an AngularJS question, not an Angular (Angular is any version beyond 2). I update your question if you don't mind

Comment: Question is not clear